# Android Studio generate signed bundle/apk

Tags: android-studio, apk

I was generate signed bundle/apk and uploaded on the PlayStore. and i want to add a new release. but i can't generate a new release i got just app.aab.

[The output when generate signed bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFWKr.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can upload abb (bundle) and its even more recommend to do so..

anyway you can choose apk as well.. did you choose the "apk" ?

[image]

then chose apk instead of bundle

Comment: You are saying that you can upload a new aab as an update to the app?